# Getting Invalid context uri when calling Spotify API start playback

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to start playback of a playlist with this endpoint https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/start-a-users-playback/

It works for artist and album if my body json is this:

```
{"context_uri":"spotify:artist:1FcB6xMihhP9Hb6AdGVbWe"}
```

but not for playlists with this:

```
{"context_uri:"spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DWVl5gPCRkquk"}
```

In the documentation it says I can specify playlists, artists, or albums, but I get the below response when trying to play a playlist:

```
Status code: 400, response : {  "error" : {    "status" : 400,    "message" : "Invalid context uri"  }}
```

Comment: Just looks like your playlist uri is incorrect. The correct format includes username as well spotify:user:spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DWVl5gPCRkquk.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you. I wish the documentation listed the correct formats.

Comment: @jooon do you know if this is still valid ? you mentioned you need to include username, so you mean to rplace :user: with the according username ? couldn't it get to work...

Answer (score 1):

The format for `context_uris` for playlists is:

```
"spotify:user:{user_id}:playlist:37i9dQZF1DWVl5gPCRkquk"
```

Where `user_id` is your username.

Answer (score 0):

The valid uri should be e.g. "spotify:playlist:aaclI7AQBATZ5XXJF73BZK"